# How can I use cramers rule to solve this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have deduced and found three equations in which I need to solve this problem (Stated Below)
How can I format this to fit into matrices to be solved with Cramers rule.

The formulas I have are:

R=100000

C = 0.1(R-(P+F))

P = 0.05(R-(C))

F = 0.4(R-(C=F))

Would the matrix look similar to

0.1   1   1

0.5   1   0

0.4   1   1

Is this correct and if not where did I go wrong :/, thank you! <3

Full Question:
A company earns before-tax profits of 100,000 dollars. It has agreed to contribute 10 
percent of its after-tax profits to the Red Cross Relief Fund. It must pay a provincial 
tax of 5 percent of its profits (after the Red Cross donation) and a federal tax of 40 
percent of its profit (after the donation and provincial taxes are paid). Use Cramer’s 
rule to determine how much the company pays in provincial taxes, federal taxes, and 
Red Cross donation. {Hint: Let C, P, and F represent the amounts of the charitable 
donation, provincial tax, and federal tax, respectively. Since after-tax profits are 
$100,000 – (P+F), therefore: C = 0.1 [100,000 – (P+F) ]. Use the other pieces of 
information given in this question to write two other equations, one for P and one 
for F. Solve these equations simultaneously using Cramer’s rule.}

---

Steps

Original Matrix

P       C      F

Determinate = -0.957

0.1____1_____0.1 = 10000

1_____0.05____0 = 5000

0.4___0.4_____1 = 40000

---

**P**       C      F

Determinate = -4500

10000____1_____0.1 = 10000

5000_____0.05____0 = 5000

40000___0.4_____1 = 40000

---

P       **C**      F

Determinate = -5700

0.1____10000_____0.1 = 10000

1_____5000____0 = 5000

0.4___40000_____1 = 40000

---

P       C      **F**

Determinate = -37620

0.1____1_____10000 = 10000

1_____0.05____5000 = 5000

0.4___0.4_____40000 = 40000

Then I just divided P, C, F determinate by the original one

Comment: A matrix corresponds to the coefficients of linear equations with the same variables in the same order. You need to use some algebra to put your equations into the right form first -- you might want to start by distributing the constants outside of the parentheses.

Comment: So C=10000 - 0.1P - 0.1F, P = 5000 - 0.05C, F = 40000 - 0.4C -0.4F?

Comment: Almost. Now you need to put the constant (eg the 10000 in the first equation) on one side of the equation, and all the variables on the other side.

Comment: so 10000 = -0.1P - 0.1F, 5000 = -0.05C, 40000 = -0.4c - 0.4f?

Comment: The variables are all still different, so would I add a, as an example 0c in the first equation to make the matrix

so it would become 10000 = -0.1P - 0.1F + 0c?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And be sure to keep the variables in the same order in each equation.

Comment: but the "P" equation becomes, 50000 = -0.05C + 0F + 0C, giving me, 0 as the determinate, and I cant divide by 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18265/discussion-between-laura-and-jonny).

Comment: What are the unknown variables, and known constants?

Comment: See: https://www.google.com.eg/books/edition/Self_Help_to_CBSE_Applied_Mathematics_So/9W4_EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cramer+rule+after+tax+profit+red+cross&pg=PA257&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little algebra to put the equations into the format $xP + yC + zF = w$ where $x,y,z,w$ are constants.

R=100000

$C = 0.1(R-(P+F))$ => $C = 10000 - 0.1(P+F)$ => $0.1P + C + 0.1F = 10000 $

$P = 0.05(R-(C))$ => $P = 5000 - 0.05C$ => $P + 0.05C + 0F = 5000$

$F = 0.4(R-(C=F))$ => becomes something, depending on what your typo here means.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: so P = 4602.19, C = 5959.11, F = 39310.34 :D Thanks for all the help!

Comment: However when I sub it back into the equation is proves wrong ):

Comment: Definitely not right -- can you edit your question to show your algebra steps ?

Comment: I edited it for you :/ thanks for the help